# postman: How to add minutes to a dateTime while looping with JS?

Tags: javascript, loops, datetime, testing, postman

I am trying to add 15 mins to a dateTime(2100-01-04T08:00:00) while looping.
For each run I want to add 15 minutes , so it would be 2100-01-04T08:15:00 , 2100-01-04T08:30:00 and so on…
I know I can do the below:
var moment = require('moment');
moment().add(15, 'minutes').toISOString();
But this will add 15 minutes to the current moment time but I want to add 15 minutes to 2100-01-04T08:00:00.

Is this possible in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create an `addMinutes()` function to add a number of minutes to a date, you can then use a `while` loop to loop until a specified end date is reached.

In the example below, we'll add 15 minutes to the date until the end date is reached.

```js
function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + minutes);
    return newDate;
}

let date = new Date('2100-01-04T08:00:00');
let endDate = new  Date('2100-01-04T09:00:00');

let deltaMinutes = 15;
while (date <= endDate) {
    console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'));
    date = addMinutes(date, 15);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using any third party libraries like momentJs.
The default javascript Date object has methods for getting the minutes property for a date object - getMinutes() and also another method for updating this minutes property - setMinutes().
Combining them both, you can achieve your required answer.

```js
let x = new Date('2100-01-04T08:00:00') 
for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++){
  x.setMinutes(x.getMinutes()+15);
  console.log(x)
}
```

P.S, remove 'postman' from your question. It has nothing to do with the problem you are facing.